# Prolog list of numbers generator

Tags: numbers, prolog, generator

I would like to make a generator that makes a list from type [a,b,c], starts from [0,0,0] the next is [0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2] and so on to infinity.

I am sorry I said it with long example I just don't know how to explain it in English.

If I had a range (let's say it's up to 10) I would use between like this:

```
genCombo([A,B,C]):-
        between(0,10,A),
        between(0,10,B),
        between(0,10,C).
```

But when it's to infinity I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've limited the range, to get a clean display, but you can replace 3 with inf. Of course, don't put the conjunction in findall :)
The idea it's that only one of the generators runs to infinity, others two (or whatever you want) are limited by that value...

```
?- findall([B,C,A], (between(0, 3, A), between(0, A, B), between(0, A, C)), L), maplist(writeln,L).
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,1,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,1]
[0,0,2]
[0,1,2]
[0,2,2]
[1,0,2]
[1,1,2]
[1,2,2]
[2,0,2]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,2]
[0,0,3]
[0,1,3]
[0,2,3]
[0,3,3]
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`between/3` takes the atom `inf` as its second argument:

```
?- between(0, inf, X).
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 7 ;
X = 8 ;
X = 9 ;
X = 10 ;
X = 11 ;
Etc.
```

Generating lists in the requested order is probably best achieved using constraints... From the top of my head I come up with the following implementation that does not use constraints:

```
go([A,B,C]):-
  between(0, inf, X1),
  succ(X1, X2),
  member(A, [X1,X2]),
  member(B, [X1,X2]),
  member(C, [X1,X2]),
  \+ (A == X2, B == X2, C == X2).
```

Example of use:

```
?- go(L).
L = [0, 0, 0] ;
L = [0, 0, 1] ;
L = [0, 1, 0] ;
L = [0, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 0, 0] ;
L = [1, 0, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 0] ;
L = [1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 2] ;
```

Comment: Yes but that way it gets only [0,0,1] , [0,0,2], [0,0,3] and so on and never changes the other 2 numbers.

Comment: @chnging I have added an ad-hoc implementation that produces lists in the order you describe. Be aware that neater solutions should exist!

Answer (score 1):

In the following we use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

First, consider:

```
?- Zs = [_,_,_], Zs ins 0..sup, sum(Zs,#=,3), labeling([],Zs).
  Zs = [0,0,3]
; Zs = [0,1,2]
; Zs = [0,2,1]
; Zs = [0,3,0]
; Zs = [1,0,2]
; Zs = [1,1,1]
; Zs = [1,2,0]
; Zs = [2,0,1]
; Zs = [2,1,0]
; Zs = [3,0,0].
```

Next, generalize `sum(Zs,#=,3)` and 
use `length(_,Sum)` 
for fair enumeration... and we're **done!**

```
?- length(_,Sum), Zs = [_,_,_], Zs ins 0..sup, sum(Zs,#=,Sum), labeling([],Zs).
  Sum = 0, Zs = [0,0,0]
; Sum = 1, Zs = [0,0,1]
; Sum = 1, Zs = [0,1,0]
; Sum = 1, Zs = [1,0,0]
; Sum = 2, Zs = [0,0,2]
; Sum = 2, Zs = [0,1,1]
; Sum = 2, Zs = [0,2,0]
; Sum = 2, Zs = [1,0,1]
; Sum = 2, Zs = [1,1,0]
; Sum = 2, Zs = [2,0,0]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [0,0,3]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [0,1,2]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [0,2,1]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [0,3,0]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [1,0,2]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [1,1,1]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [1,2,0]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [2,0,1]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [2,1,0]
; Sum = 3, Zs = [3,0,0]
; Sum = 4, Zs = [0,0,4] 
...
```